# Set default value radio button in template

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I'm trying to set a default value in a template file for a radio button on my register form.

Female has value 0 and male has value 1. This is the code I use to set a default value:

```
    $form['field_personal_details']['und'][0]['field_gender']['und']['#default_value'] = '1';
```

I also tried

```
    $form['field_personal_details']['und'][0]['field_gender']['und']['#value'] = '1';
```

This should check the radio button as male, but it doesn't work.
Whenever I set the default value to male through the UI it does work and I get the same outputs when I do a dpm.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add direct user registration form alter and try to change "1" to 1.

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id) 
{

  $form['field_gender']['und']['#default_value'] = 1;
    <---or ---> 
  $form['field_personal_details']['und'][0]['field_gender']['und']['#default_value'] = 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) (or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)) to alter forms:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'foo') {
    $form['field_personal_details'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['field_gender'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = '1';
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay! How come I can change the value from text fields in my template though and not the radio buttons?

Comment: I have no idea :) I just know you're only supposed to alter forms with a form-alter hook - it's something to do with the elements already having been processed in `drupal_get_form()`